# phpmailer get recipients from text file

Tags: php, file, phpmailer

before I post this thread, I search my question, but I see only how to get recipients from database or other is with only mail() function.

I want to send emails from txt file, but my code send only first email from text document.

```
  <?php
  include("msd/mail.php");
  $file = fopen("emails.txt",  "r");
       $line = fgets($file);
        $to = $line;
  $subject = "Approve your signup";
  $body = "Hello, to approve your registration please click this link";
  $mail = new Mail();
  $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
  $mail->FromName = "myweb.com";
  $mail->addAddress($to);
  $mail->subject($subject);
  $mail->body($body);
  if(!$mail->send())
 {
            echo "Error Sending Email!"; 
         }
         else
        { 
            echo "Mail sent!"; 
        }

    ?>
```

emails.txt

```
test@gmail.com
test2@gmail.com
test3@gmail.com
```

Comment: Is it an e-mail per line? If so, you'll need a loop.

Comment: *"but I see only how to get recipients from database or other is with only mail() function."* - It would be safer than storing email addresses in a text file and easier to manage. I hope you've taken the proper steps to protect that file.

Comment: how to do that with loop?

Answer (score 0):

You need read text file line by line and then take it into a array and run loop to add address

```
<?php
    include("msd/mail.php");
    $file = fopen("test.txt","r");
    $emailArray = array();
    while(! feof($file))
    {
        $emailArray[] = fgets($file). "<br />";
    }
    $subject = "Approve your signup";
    $body = "Hello, to approve your registration please click this link";
    $mail = new Mail();
    $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
    $mail->FromName = "myweb.com";
    foreach($emailArray as $val)
    {
        $mail->addAddress($val);
    }
    $mail->subject($subject);
    $mail->body($body);
    if(!$mail->send())
    {
        echo "Error Sending Email!"; 
    }
    else
    { 
        echo "Mail sent!"; 
    }

?>
```

Comment: @SIngo Follow the steps to debug php mailer by setting debug level and I hope you have Included the files and also check php error log.

Comment: Mailer Error: You must provide at least one recipient email address. this is give me

Comment: Your text file should have email id one per line as below,

nitish@asd.com
abc@asd.com
xyz@xyz.in

Comment: in my text file has only one email and is still get me same message

Answer (score 0):

You can always do this by loop. Please try this code:

```
<?php
  include("msd/mail.php");
  $file = fopen("emails.txt",  "r");
  if($file){
    $array = explode("\n", fread($fp, filesize($file)));
  }
  $subject = "Approve your signup";
  $body = "Hello, to approve your registration please click this link";
  $mail = new Mail();
  $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
  $mail->FromName = "myweb.com";
  for($i=0;$i<=count($array)-1;$i++){
        $mail->AddAddress($array[$i]);
  } 
  $mail->subject($subject);
  $mail->body($body);
  if(!$mail->send())
    {
        echo "Error Sending Email!"; 
    }
    else
    { 
        echo "Mail sent!"; 
    }
```

Note Please be sure that the file gets read by php

Comment: Can you please check that normal email is going from the server. In case the codes is getting tested in localhost you need to make the SMTP configurations, so that email goes out..

Comment: My first code which I posted is working and I receive email, but your code show me "Error sending email!"

Comment: Please print the array to check the emails obtained after reading the file. Then you are using phpmailer right, so please check this:
You need to call the AddAddress method once for every recipient. Like so:

$mail->AddAddress('person1@domain.com', 'Person One');
$mail->AddAddress('person2@domain.com', 'Person Two');

This is only written in the code. Please debug a bit.
Also as per your emails.txt the emails are 
test@gmail.com
test2@gmail.com
test3@gmail.com
Please use valid emails for testing..

Comment: Warning: filesize() expects parameter 1 to be a valid path, resource given in /var/www/html/bb.php on line 5

Warning: fread(): Length parameter must be greater than 0 in /var/www/html/bb.php on line 5
Error Sending Email !Mailer Error: You must provide at least one recipient email address.

Comment: Please print_r($array). My probable guess is that your file is not getting read as a result of which the $array  is not getting made and hence you get this message "You must provide at least one recipient email address"

Comment: Array ( [0] => but my file is with chmod 777 problem is not in file rights.

Comment: Please try using Document root like this:
echo $file=$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'/emails.txt';
Please check the path whether its ok or not...

Comment: same thing :( my first code is working and i receive emails, but  your code is not working

Comment: I received the emails . I usually test the answers and if it works then only answer it.